# Automatically add private qualifier to fields in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to automatically add the private qualifier while new variables are declared in Eclipse?

In a way I would like to override the default access to private

Comment: I don't think that this Feature is really needed. If you are a practiced coder it shouldn't be a Problem to Write it by Youssef.

Comment: Eclipse normally only does code changes when explicitly asking for it.  How would you expect this feature to trigger?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: You can already tell Eclipse to add `final` to fields wherever it can. It's a save action, so it checks for and takes opportunities when you save. Making a field private could be done the same way.

Comment: @TomAnderson save actions are nice, but they still need to be explicitly enabled.  Also I believe anything like this would go in the Clean Source menus instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Oh sure, you would have to enable this. I assume the asker does not want everybody's copy of Eclipse to do this to their code without asking them, just his.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this.

However, the way i write code, it would rarely be necessary. That's because i rarely define fields by hand; instead, i let Eclipse create them, and when it does that, it makes them private.

Say i want to create a class `Foo` with a single field `bar` of type `int`. Start with:

```
public class Foo {
}
```

Put the cursor in the class body, hit control-space, and choose 'default constructor' from the proposals menu. You now have:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Delete the helpful comment. Now manually add a constructor parameter for `bar`:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(int bar) {
    }
}
```

Now put the cursor on the declaration of `bar` and hit control-1. From the proposals menu, choose 'assign parameter to new field':

```
public class Foo {
    private final int bar;

    public Foo(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;

    }
}
```

Bingo. You now have a private field.

There is a similar sequence of automatic operations which can create a field from an existing expression in a method (first creating a local variable, then promoting it to a field).

Comment: I don't always use ctr+1 or ctr+2 but probably its time I start using it more often
Probably something useful would be to hit some shortcut while you highlight the variable, that makes it static, final or private (based on the shortcut) but eclipse obviously does not have it.

I know about the save actions but they apply globally to the whole file and I don't like that

Comment: Control-1 and control-space are two of the most important keystrokes in Eclipse, and you should definitely start using them more. They're great! I don't use control-2 at all myself, but i know plenty of people do. Yes, shame there aren't shortcuts to adjust variables like that. There are still plenty of useful things Eclipse doesn't do, sadly.

Comment: @Tom Anderson Crtl-2 l is a very good use of ctrl-2 and worth using!

Comment: @reevesy: Thanks for the tip. Ctrl-2 L assigns something to a local variable, right? I usually do that with shift-alt-L with an expression selected, or ctrl-1 then hitting down arrow to "Assign statement to new local variable". One of the nice things about Eclipse is that there are several different styles to using it!

Comment: @Tom, yes it does assign to a local var. Never tried shift-atl-L will check it out. Yeah you are right about serval different styles, I've been using eclipse for years and still finding shortcuts!

Answer (score 0):

If you consider it more important to you than performance and readability, I suppose you could configure a relatively convenient solution as follows. I wouldn't do this myself.

For class and instance variables, modify the class template in preferences to incorporate this:

```
private static Object fields = new Object () {
    // declare all class variables here
};

private Object vars = new Object () {
    // declare all instance variables here
};
```

For local variables, modify the method template in preferences to incorporate this:

```
private Object locals = new Object () {
    // declare all local variables here
};
```

Class variable `x` will be declared in `fields`. It will be private at `this.class.fields.x`.

Instance variable `y` will be declared in `vars`. It will be private at `this.vars.y`.

Local variable `z` will be declared in `locals`. It will be private at `locals.z`.

If you do this, you can expect your entire program to be slower and use more memory that it would otherwise.